# How can I move my tool bar to next view

Tags: iphone, toolbar

I have a tool bar and I want that to be visible on next views as well.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view with your toolbar and add it as a subview to all other views who need it ;-)

Comment: In the corresponding files (.h and .m) wich are created automatically if you want while you create the view...

Comment: i am new to this iphone development so plz help me 
i hav created buttons view controller and how shuld i add it as a sub view to my root view ..can show me simple code..

Comment: [self addSubview:[Tbar view]];
i am using this gives warning like rootview controller is may not respond to this...
i hav added this in view loaded in root view controller

Comment: i hav created tbar using toolbarviewcontroller